# calling overridden function in superclass from subclass in JAVA

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

Suppose I have two classes A and B where A is a superclass of B. Now, I write a function (override), say funct() in both the classes. Then, if I want to call the funct() in A from an object of B, is it possible?

Comment: @Dukeling What I meant was that you cannot call the superclass method from outside the object itself.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija I just wanted to know about the implementation, whether it is possible to do it or no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given classes like

```
class A {
    public void funct() {...}
}

class B extends A {
    @Override 
    public void funct() {...}
}
```

You ask

> Then, if I want to call the funct() in A from an object of B, is it
>   possible?

So let's take

```
B b = new B();
b.funct(); 
A a = b;
a.funct();
((A)b).funct();
```

The above all do the same thing because of polymorphism and late-binding.

The only way to call the superclass' implementation is to get a reference to that member through the `super` keyword.

```
class A {
    public void funct() {...}
}

class B extends A {
    @Override 
    public void funct() {
        super.funct();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, we cannot directly invoke the over-ridden function just by using an object, right? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
class A {
    public void f() {...}
}

class B extends A {
    @Override public void f() { super.f(); }
}
```

Is that what you want?

If instead you want to call `A#f()` directly on an instance of type B, you must provide a placeholder function for that:

```
class B extends A {
    @Override public void f() { ... }
    public void superF() { super.f(); }
}

new B().f(); // calls B#f();
new B().superF(); // calls A#f();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have trick such as this situation to operate it in an illogical manner using Flag argument in funct() method :D, like this:

```
class A {

    public void funct(boolean callSuper) {
        // avoid using callSuper arg here 
    }
}

class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void funct(boolean callSuper) {
        if (callSuper) {
            super.funct(callSuper);
            return;//if return type is void
        } else {
            //do here the functionality if the flag is false 
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
class A {

    public void funct() {

    }
}

class B extends A {

    private boolean callSuper = false;

    @Override
    public void funct() {
        if (callSuper) {
            super.funct(); // call A.funct() functionality 
            setCallSuper(false);
        } else {
            //do here the functionality of B.funct() if the flag is false 
        }
    }

    public void setCallSuper(boolean callSuper){
        this.callSuper = callSuper;
    }
}
```